# Moving controls forward and/or back in a form

Tags: vb.net, panel

I am trying to move a panel forward when I MouseDown, currently I am doing this using
    `panel.BringToFront()`
Then when I MouseUp I want to send the panel back, i am trying to do this using 
    `panel.SendToBack()`
When i run, it moves the panel forward, but doesnt send it backwards again. Are there other ways to manipulate a control in the Z-axis other than using BringToFront or SendToBack.

I am using VB Express 2008.

Comment: post your code that handles the mouse events.  Need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes try:

```
 Me.panel.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(me.panel, zIndex) 'Put instead of zIndex the Zorder number that you want
```